# How to do a Sheet Swap in Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-analysis, amazon-quicksight, tableau-desktop, quicksight-embedding

I want to swap visualization of the same values from a table to a pie chart or a bar graph. While this is possible in tableau I am not sure if it is in Quicksight. I am new to Quicksight so any help on how to do it would be great !

I know it would be done using parameters and calculated fields but i don't understand how to make it jump across the sheet can u help me with logic

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Properties/Actions (in the visual) and Show/Hide via parameters which visual to show.

Regards José Burrull

Comment: thanks for the response but there is no option for hide/view in quicksight according to my knowledge

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).